# Extracting, stacking and calculating Standard Deviation from NetCDF (.nc) to produce single standard deviation and Mean image in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, netcdf

I have a NetCDF file for several years of monthly Climate data ( Precipitation,PET,Temp,etc) data from CRU 3.22 (Climate Research Unit). I want to extract a subset of the dataset namely 2000-2010. And subsequently process the datasets into raster as annual mean and annual standard deviation and also produce a mean and a standard deviation for the period. To simplify the process i want to use either Python or ModelBuilder.

How to extract,stack and calculate Standard Deviation from a NetCDF (.nc) to produce a single standard deviation and Mean image?

Comment: How exactly are "Make NetCDF Raster layer" and "Cell Statistics" used to arrive at the resulting mean or std image?

Comment: The first step is adding NetCDF as raster layer (multiband) as explained  in http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004600000011000000. Then the tool that you are looking for is Cell Statistics which is in here, http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000007q000000.htm. These two steps can easily be elaborated in a model via Model Builder.

Answer (score 2):

I used IDV ( Integrated Data Viewer) software to extract (subset the .nc files). This gives 120 ( in the 2001-2010 period) monthly data. I used IDV again to process the monthly .nc files into annual means using a built-in timeseries average formula for each year. Data>Formula>Grids>Timesteps>Average Timesteps.This yields annual means. The annual means were converted into rasters using batch processing of Make netCDF raster tool in ArcGIS 10.3.

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the same problem, could you please help me? I'm trying to import a netcdf file exported from arcgis pro in IDV, but is giving 'no gridded data found'. I have posted my question here: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/export-voxel-layer-sections/m-p/1265926#M66424